# Can three summoned hags form a coven?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, dnd-adventurers-league, summoning

It is possible, with DM Approval, for high level player character to summon a trio of hags (either a trio of Sea Hags from a single Level 8 Casting of Conjure Woodland Beings, or a trio of higher CR hags by three separate castings of Conjure Fey). Both of those spells have a duration of an hour (or two, if the Extended Metamagic spell option is somehow applied onto them), after which point the hags disappear.

With DM Approval, can such a trio of temporarily summoned hags form a coven (do they potentially have the time to do so) and/or can it be said, again with DM Approval, that they were already in a coven when summoned ?

This is within the scope of Adventurers League Organized Play, where Rules as Written are to be followed, with a modicum of Rules as Cool. I ask, because there might be something I'm missing.

Comment: Is there any benefit to the Hags for being in a coven? Does it actually matter, or is it just something cool to tack on as a side note?

Comment: @RevenantBacon Hags being in a coven gives them some special shared spellcasting !

Comment: @GaelL might be worth adding that to the question for clarity

Comment: Note that hags in a coven have a higher CR and thus you cannot summon a whole coven with *conjure woodland beings* (in-coven sea hags are CR 4).

Comment: @Szega Ah, then, it would only be possible with three separate castings of Conjure Fey, if the DM agrees, according to the answers below !

Answer (score 7):

## Probably not

[Hags](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-h#Hags) (MM, 176) discusses how and when a group of three hags will form a coven:

> When hags must work together, they form covens, in spite of their selfish natures. A coven is made up of hags of any type, all of whom are equals within the group. However, each of the hags continues to desire more personal power.

It is impossible for you to summon three members of a specific coven because the CR rating becomes 4 and that's out of the spell's scope. It may be possible for them to quickly form one, but coming up with the narrative for doing so may be trick given the time constraints. It's also unclear how quickly they can form the coven.

Looking at this from purely mechanical perspective, I don't think it's likely, but it is absolutely within the realm to allow it because it does meet the requirements of 3 hags.

However, the odds of the summoning an existing coven with their hag eye is pretty slim.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's true, the Eye wouldn't follow, they'd need to make a new one *real quick* !

Comment: @GaelL The ritual takes an hour...

Comment: Oh darn ! ummm, can a coven function without their eye? (aka, can they benefit from their shared spellcasting without the eye nearby?)

Comment: @GaelL yeah, it's an extra not a requirement

Answer (score 3):

## The GM decides.

Basically all summoning spells in DND 5e leave the selection of the creatures summoned to the decision of the GM. As a result, if they decide that such a spell summons a trio of hags, then they can also decide whether or not they have access to the special coven spellcasting since that’s a variation of their stat block.